# Can War God's Blessing be applied to Bigby's Hand attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, cleric

Does War God's Blessing affect Bigby's Hand's attacks?

The description states that a creature can benefit from it, but the hand is an object. PHB pg.63:

> When a **creature** within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can
>   use your reaction to grant that creature a +10 bonus to the roll,
>   using your Channel Divinity.

On the other hand, the description for Bigby's Hand attack states that the attack roll is made using the caster's stats, not the hand's, so one could argue it's an attack made by the wizard, therefore justifying the Blessing. PHB 218:

> The hand strikes one creature or object within 5 feet
>   of it. Make a melee spell attack for the hand using your game
>   statistics.

What's the correct interpretation for the blessing in this situation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will apply to an attack roll made for a Bigby's Hand only if the *caster/controller* of Bigby's Hand is within the Blessing's range when they make an attack roll for something they are making the Hand do. The Hand does not have to be within range, since it is not making the roll and is not a creature anyway.

This is because it is the caster/controller who is making the attack. Bigby's Hand makes it clear that it's the caster actively doing the attacking, merely using the Hand at a remove to do so:

> … as a bonus action on your subsequent turns…
>
> Make a melee spell attack for the hand…
>
> If you succeed, the hand pushes the target…
>
> … you have advantage on the check…

In each way that the Hand can attack, it is the caster actively controlling the Hand and contesting the caster's own ability (their attack bonuses and rolls) against the enemy the Hand is attacking.

Comment: Your interpretation of the caster being the attacker is supported by this ruling from Crawford regarding Spiritual Weapon: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722864238935482368